# ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have this in my .htaccess

```
RedirectMatch 301 /mice-group http://web.com/mice-group-meeting
```

And return ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

With Redirect 301 doesn't redirect, so how I can do this?

Solved:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/mice-group$ http://web.com/mice-group-meeting
```

Comment: I have more Redirects, but, the redirect mice-group to mice-group-meeting isn't duplicate,

Comment: Please actually read the linked question. It is an exact duplicate of your question.

Comment: Thanks, added RedirectMatch 301 ^/mice-group$ http://web.com/mice-group-meeting is solved